# С чего подступиться в задании по python'у

Tags: python

В задании всё указано, но обьясню как получится.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно написать код. В задании указывается что два элемента из таблицы участвуют в реакции. Нужно найти эти элементы. Вопрос как? Помогите начать, а дальше разберусь сам.
Пробовал решать через систему, получилось что то типо:

F(t=0)=A1+A2=4

F(T=10^-10)=(4-A2) x e^((-10^10)/(тау1)10^-9) + A2e^((-10^-10)/(тау2)10^-9))

Помогите что делать и правильно ли вообще кодить после через систему?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно найти эти элементы. Вопрос как?

Вообще-то, это вопрос не по программированию. Это вопрос по дисциплине, котрая у нас называлась МОРЭ - "Методы обработки результатов эксперимента".

И ответ тут довольно очевиден:

1. Из файла экспериментальных данных, вычисляем **фактический** коэффициент затухания "тау".
2. Так как в задании сказано, что образец - смесь всего двух веществ, то пытаемся скомбинировать фактическое значение из пары тех, что есть в таблице.

Например, мы получили **фактическое** тау = 212.5. Тупо разглядывая таблицу видим, что это (скорее всего) 33% нафталина и 66% антрацена.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я забыл добавить немаловажные моменты и в чём именно пайтон должен участвовать.
Эксперимент длится 10^-6 с и каждый раз записывается замер 10^-10 с.Замеры сигнала длится 10-^6 с и через каждые 10^-10 записывается значение , получается список с данными, что то типа [4, 3.96, 3.93, 3.90, 3.87 ....]. 
4 это когда время равно 0, потом когда время равно 10^-10 значение сигнала =3.96. 
Потом при времени 10^-10+10^-10 и значение = 3.93. И так, пока время не станет = 10^-6. 
Пайтон как то должен участвовать в анализе, не знаю правда как, поэтому буду признателен, если ответите.

Comment: @БабайБев - "Пайтон как то должен участвовать в анализе"
- Я не буду Вам пересказывать теорию анализа временных рядов данных. Библиотека pandas - вот основа для такого анализа. Посмотрите хотя бы эту статью:   https://habr.com/ru/post/207160/